# Adding dynamic number of parameters to new Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have created a class which reads a CSV and returns an output file with  a specified subset of columns from the original file (as well as running logic on the cells) and I was wondering if it is possible to somehow add a dynamic number of row cells to a datatable?  For example.  I use this class across multiple projects however depending on how many headers I want to use in the output CSV file I need to change the line I populate my datatable rows on to include more parameters based on the number of headers.  EG-  **3 headers** will require `dt.Rows.Add(item[0], item[1], item[2]);`

Is there a way to somehow get it to do the following?  **PSEUDOCODE**

```
dt.Rows.Add(
    foreach(var c in item){
        add another parameter for item
    }
);
```

I'm looking to add a dynamic number of parameters to a datatable row based on the number of headers.  I've got the code on hand if required will edit upon request.

Answer (score 0):

Each `DataRow` in a `DataTable` has the same number of columns which is determined by the structure of the table. You may build this table and its columns (once) dynamically however.

You may set just a subset of the *columns* and leave the rest empty:

```
row[5] = whatever;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.  I didn't realize you can add a string[] array of values to a datatable row using the following:

```
string[] row = { "cell1value", "cell2value", "cell3value" };
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```